# Using environment specific configuration files in Node.js

Tags: node.js

Unlike Rails, there doesn't seem to be an accepted way of loading environment specific config files in Node.js.

Currently I'm using the following:

`config/development.js` and `config/production.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    'db': 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/example_dev',
    'port': 3002
};
```

Followed by the following at the top of my `app.js` file:

`var config = require('./config/' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '.js');`

This pattern works pretty well, however it forces me to pass along this config file to any modules that need it. This gets kind of clunky, for instance:

`var routes = require('./routes')(config);`

.. and in `routes/index.js`:

```
modules.export = function(config) {
    this.index = function...
    this.show = function...
};
```

Etc, etc. The module pattern just seems to be pretty clunky when dealing with something that should be global, like configuration settings. I could require the configuration file at the top of every file that needs it as well, but that doesn't seem ideal either.

Does anyone have a best practice for including a configuration file and making it globally available?

Comment: in the config files you could do `config = {...}` (without `var`), and it will be global...

Comment: or `config = require('./config/' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '.js');` (again, without `var`)

Answer (score 0):

You could just attach it to the global process object:

**app.js:**

```
var config = require('./config/' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '.js');
process.config = config;
```

**aywhere else in your app**

```
console.log(process.config);
```

Yes, it's a bit dangerous in that it can get overwritten anywhere, but it's still a pretty simple approach.